# does service or handler go to sleep too when device's lcd goes off?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-handler

I want to develop a sleep tracking app that should work even when device's screen gets off. I'm curious about whether `Service` or `Handler` go to sleep when device screen is off. I learned the life-cycle of activity, so I don't think a `Handler` would work since activities go to sleep when device's screen is off, and `Handlers` are dependent on its activity. But the `Service` is a background process, so I think it might work.

So I want the device to be alive even when device's screen is off. Could you give me some advice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application will be paused after a while if device screen is locked. The CPU will sleep until user wakes the device, so, your `Service` won't do anything while device sleeps.

If you want to perform some action even when the screen is turned off, you can acquire a `WakeLock`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html
But be careful, using the `WakeLock` too much will drain battery fast.

Also, another class that may be useful for you is `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

What it does is, it receives some `Intent` and acquires a `WakeLock` for you so that you can finish your work in a `Service`. Without this you have no guarantee that device will finish the work and not go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Services pause when the screen turns off. This is done to prevent battery draining.
In your case, since you want your service to run for a longer period of time, you can consider using `PowerManager.WakeLock`
Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).

But you should keep in mind that using WakeLocks might affect the device's battery backup to a great extent.

Comment: I don't think that service will keep running for a long time when device's screen is off. Why do we need `startWakefulService ` then? By default there is no wake lock, thus, service will be paused till device is awake.

Answer (score -1):

> does service or handler go to sleep too when device's lcd goes off?

No, Your service will run in to the background all the time until user force stop that service.

If you want your service to live all the time then you need to return [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) to `onStartCommand()`

Comment: Service stops when device screen goes off.